# How I can format moment.js date in javascript datarangepicker?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

i want to change the format of date (momentjs) from mm/ddYYYY to dd/mm/YYYY in daterangepicker. if I use the method .format(ddmmYYYY) it doesn't work

i try to change the method to format but it doesn't work well

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            //I want to change the format here
            var start = moment();
            var end = moment();

            function cb(start, end) {
            $('#dashboard-report-range span').html(start + ' - ' + end);
            }

            $('#dashboard-report-range').daterangepicker({
                startDate: start,
                endDate: end,
                locale: {
                    "fromLabel": "From",
                    "toLabel": "To",
                    "customRangeLabel": "Modify",
                    cancelLabel: 'Clear',
                    applyLabel: 'Apply'
                },
                ranges: 
                {
                    //I want to change the format here for all elements
                   'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                   'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                   'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                   'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                   'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                   'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
                },
            }, cb);

            cb(start, end);

        });
        </script>
```

Actually the date is printed with format dd/mm/YYYY and if I try to change the format the output is NanNanNan

Comment: Add `format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'` to the daterangepicker's locale config

Comment: `console.log(["!namtaB".split("").reverse().join(""),Array(16).join('wat' - 1)].reverse().join(", "))`

Comment: @phuzi Sorry, what is the property?

Comment: `moment` objects don't have a format

Comment: @phuzi I meant the property od datarangepicker

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what format the date range picker will use by adding `format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'` to the daterangepicker's locale config:

```js
$(function() {

  //I want to change the format here
  var start = moment();
  var end = moment();

  function cb(start, end) {
    $('#dashboard-report-range span').html(start + ' - ' + end);
  }

  $('#dashboard-report-range').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    locale: {
      "fromLabel": "From",
      "toLabel": "To",
      "customRangeLabel": "Modify",
      cancelLabel: 'Clear',
      applyLabel: 'Apply',
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY' // <-- Add this line
    },
    ranges: {
      //I want to change the format here for all elements
      'Today': [moment(), moment()],
      'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
      'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
      'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
      'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
      'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    },
  }, cb);

  cb(start, end);

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="dashboard-report-range" />
```

Comment: I tried to put it but it doesn't work, could it be that I left some library?

Comment: When i click on Yesterday or any other the date format return to mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: If I run your code it works well, but in my page it doesn't work well

Comment: What versions of jquery, moment and daterangepicker are you using?

Comment: for datapicker I use this -> <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

Comment: @regard Don't think it will be the CSS. What specific versions are you using?

Comment: datatrangepicker-bs3.css i use this

Comment: @regard that's only CSS for styling of the daterangepicker and not relevant to my question. Are you using jQuery 3.4.1, moment 2.24.0 and daterangepicker 3.0.5?